# How to get form values to a confirm page, before submitting to database

Tags: php, forms

I cant echo the form firstname to the php form so they can confirm the details before submitting the text.

This is in my php script.

```
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value=  <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?> /> 
</td>
```

However, if i say put `<?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>` out of the form it will work.

Basically i want the all the form details into another form with the `input=hidden`, and if it is all correct they can submit this form in the php script to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confirm part will like to be something like this:

```
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value= "<?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>" /> 
</td>
```

And you'd better not echo user post value directly, use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert special characters to HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your input tag is missing quoation marks for the value of the "value" attribute, try the below code:

```
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>" /> 
</td>
```

And yes as was already mentioned, consider using some sort of sanitation on your users inputs:

```
<td>First Name</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]); ?>" /> 
</td>
```

To load the data into hidden inputs, you can use JavaScript by writing a function to be called on the `click` event of an input button.